# Apache видит только корневой URL

Tags: laravel, apache2

Клонировал репозиторий на сервер и настроил проект, но при попытке получить какую либо страницу, будь это login или register, получаю ошибку 404.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все отлично работает локально(локально проект запущен через openserver с сервером apache), видит все страницы, но в продакшене не видет кроме корня ничего.

Прикладываю .htaccess
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код надо прикладывать текстом

Answer (score 0):

Надо поменять:

```
AllowOverride None
```

на:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Важно обратить внимание на путь, которому вы прописываете `AllowOverride All`, в моем случае, это var/www/, в котором располагался проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код следует прилагать текстом.